# Migrate PHP AES encryption from mcrypt to openssl return different encrypted string

Tags: openssl, mcrypt

I am trying to change our existing encryption function using mcrypt to OpenSSL.But It creates different encrypted strings. How can we fix this issue?

```
<?php
$str    = 'test';
$method = 'AES-128-CBC';
$key    = 'o6xSYYAVl2eapPI2';
$iv     = 'fedcba9876543210';

function encrypt_mcrypt($str=NULL,$key,$iv) {
  $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', 'cbc', $iv);

  mcrypt_generic_init($td,$key,$iv);
  $encrypted = mcrypt_generic(@$td,@$str);

  mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
  mcrypt_module_close($td);

  return bin2hex(@$encrypted);
}
function encrypt_openssl($str=NULL,$key,$iv) {
  $encrypted =openssl_encrypt($str, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv); 
  return bin2hex(@$encrypted);
}


echo 'Mcrypt:'.encrypt_openssl($str,$key,$iv);
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Openssl:'.encrypt_mcrypt($str,$key,$iv);
```

**Output**

```
Mcrypt:0ab40f383b421ba465c0cbbcded97319
Openssl:57c86f3089535b3acfbe65cecbb662b9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both codes use different AES variants and paddings. The *mcrypt* code applies AES-128 and Zero padding, the *openssl* code AES-256 and PKCS7 padding. To make sure that both ciphertexts match, both codes must use the same AES variant and padding.

*mcrypt* identifies the AES variant from the key size. Since `$key` is a 16 bytes key, AES-128 is used. *openssl* determines the AES variant based on the specification passed in the 2nd parameter. Keys that are too short are padded with 0 values to the required length, keys that are too long are truncated. Here, `AES-256-CBC` is specified, i. e. AES-256 is used. The 16 bytes key `$key` is therefore padded with 0 values and extended to a size of 32 bytes.

*mcrypt* implicitly uses Zero padding for encryption, which *is not implicitly* removed during decryption. PKCS7 padding is not supported. openssl implicitly applies PKCS7 padding for encryption, which *is implicitly removed* during decryption. Zero padding is not supported. If the *openssl* code should use Zero padding or the *mcyrpt* code PKCS7 padding, this must be implemented by yourself.

With regard to the migration from *mcrypt* to *openssl*, the *openssl* code is modified in the following to be functionally identical to the *mcrypt* code, i.e. AES-128 and Zero padding is used. With regard to the AES variant, only the specification `AES-256-CBC` must be changed to `AES-128-CBC`. Concerning padding, the default PKCS7 padding must be disabled using `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` and Zero padding itself must be implemented (note that the `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` flag only disables padding, but does not enable Zero padding; the name is badly chosen):

```
<?php
$str    = "test";
$key    = 'o6xSYYAVl2eapPI2';
$iv     = 'fedcba9876543210';

function encrypt_openssl($str = NULL, $key, $iv) {

    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt(
        zeroPad($str, 16),                         // Zero pad plaintext
        'AES-128-CBC',                             // Choose AES-128 
        $key, 
        OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,   // Disable PKCS7 Padding
        $iv); 
     
    return bin2hex(@$encrypted);
}

function zeroPad($text, $bs) {
    $pad = $bs - strlen($text) % $bs;
    return ($pad < 16) ? $text .  str_repeat("\0", $pad) : $text;
}

echo 'Openssl:'.encrypt_openssl($str,$key,$iv); // Openssl:57c86f3089535b3acfbe65cecbb662b9
```

For a comparison with your result, note that you have confused the labels of the outputs, i.e. the *openssl* result is labeled `Mcrypt` and vice versa!

A final note: In general, PKCS7 padding is more reliable than Zero padding, as the former contains the information of the padding length. This is not the case with Zero padding, so when removing the padding (i.e. after decryption) it is not possible to distinguish between regular and padding bytes. There are also different Zero padding variants, e.g. one does not pad if the length of the plaintext already corresponds to an integer multiple of the blocksize (this variant uses *mcrypt*), the other one pads with a complete block in this case.